# Gstreamer 1.0 one source and two sink display

Tags: ubuntu, gstreamer-1.0

I want to capture image from camera via v4l2src, then captured image is displayed in 2 sink, one is original image and one is processed image.
Does anyone know how to do this?
I'm using gstreamer 1.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should look at the `tee` element: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-tee.html

Here is a gst-launch example fitting your needs:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src ! tee name=t \
    t. ! queue ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! \
        videoconvert ! autovideosink \
    t. ! queue ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=360,height=240 ! \
        videoconvert ! autovideosink
```